# c++ reading from either an ifstream or stringstream with same loop

Tags: c++

I have a function that either needs to read from an ifstream (text from a file on disk) or a stringstream (text in memory).

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
void myFunction(bool file,stringstream& ss){
   ifstream inFile;
   string oneline;
   if (file == true){
    //code to open file with inFile
   }
   while (getline(file==true?inFile:ss, oneline)){
   // ..process lines
   }
   ...
   ...
```

Needles to say it won't compile. Can anyone suggest a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't use `file == true`. It gives you `true` if `file` is already `true`, and and false if `file` is `false`, so there's no reason to do it, ever. Actually, since this is C++, there may be a risk that `file == true` actually gives incorrect results for some values that should be considered true.

Comment: Are you saying I should use this instead to test a boolean: if(file)

Comment: Yes. It's more concise, and better coding style. The comparison operations like `==`, `!=`, `<` etc. all produce a boolean, so if you already have a boolean, you don't need to use a comparison operator in order to get one.

Answer (score 3):

All the iostreams classes derive from common base classes. The input streams all derive from `istream` and the output streams all derive from `ostream`. Most typical functions that need to deal with an input stream or output stream (but don't really care whether it's from a file, string, etc.) just deal with a reference to an `istream` or `ostream`, something like this:

```
void myFunction(std::istream &is) {
    std::string oneline;
    while (getline(is, oneline))
       process(oneline);
}

if (file) {
    std::ifstream inFile(filename);
    myFunction(inFile);
}
else {
    std::istringstream fromMemory(...);
    myFunction(fromMemory);
}
```

Comment: I'm still confused.  getline(ss, oneline) works fine and while getline(inFile, oneline) work fine, but  getline((file)?inFile:ss, oneline)) fails with  error: no matching function for call to 'getline(void*, std::string&)'  Can i solve this with a cast?